# What does "another" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning

Recently I looked up the meaning of "superscript" in the dictionary of
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/superscript

At Point 2 of "superscript" in American, the following explanation is given with an example such as;

> a figure, letter, or symbol written above and to the side of another
>
> *in y<sup>2</sup> and x<sup>n</sup>, 2 and n are superscripts*

My question is what the "another" means in this case.  Basically another means something additional.

For example, in the case of "m<sup>2</sup>", superscript is 2 which means square meter. Why does the superscript, 2 is expressed as written above and to the side of "another"?  There are no figures, letter or symbols to the side of "m".

Please explain what "another" means in this case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The nice answers from katatahito and Jason Bassord are referring to a process called *ellipsis*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics). In your example, the words "figure, letter, or symbol" have been omitted from the end of the sentence because (1) the meaning can be inferred without them (by someone familiar with ellipsis) and (2) to include them might cause the sentence to sound  repetitive or wordy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another here is short for **another figure, letter or symbol**.

Therefore the "another" in your case of m<sup>2</sup> for meters-squared, the "m" is what "another" is referring to. "2" is written above and to the side of "m", which is another [figure, letter or symbol].

Answer (score 7):

To paraphrase the dictionary entry:

> ***a figure, letter, or symbol*** (such as <sup>*2*</sup> or <sup>*n*</sup>) written above and to the side of ***another*** (such as *y* or *n*)
>
> *in y<sup>2</sup> and x<sup>2</sup>, 2 and n are superscripts*

It is no different that saying something like this:

> The word *be* is comprised of ***one letter*** (*e*) written to the right of ***another*** (*b*).

---

From the Merriam-Webster definition of the pronoun [*another*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another):

> **1** : an additional one of the same kind : one more
>   // one copy to send out, *another* for the files

Comment: IMHO, in the paraphrasing, it would have been clearer to state "... written above and to the side of another *figure, letter, or symbol* (such as y or n)" - as it is the "another" in *isolation* which seems to be causing the OP's confusion.